# Gráfico incorrecto de valores procedentes de un fichero csv

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Queremos graficar un fichero .csv exportado desde la Web de un banco y modificado. La estructura del fichero Acatis.csv es:
[image: estructura de Acatis.csv]
Ejecutamos este script:

```
import os
# Recuperar el directorio de trabajo actual (`cwd`)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
# Change directory 
os.chdir("F:\Py_2019\Py_Udacity\Ficheros_csv")
# List all files and directories in current directory
os.listdir('.')
df = pd.read_csv("Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4.csv", index_col = "Date", parse_dates = True, 
                 decimal = ",", usecols = ["Date", "Close"], na_values = ["nan"], sep="\t")
df["Close"] = df["Close"].astype(np.float)
print (df[:3])
print (df.info())
# Plot the cumulative daily returns
df["Close"].plot(figsize=(12,8))
_ = plt.legend(loc=2);

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

La salida nos muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Es evidente que la gráfia no es correcta.
PRUEBA Nº 1 
Realizamos una prueba con un fichero .csv con cotizaciones importadas desde Yahoo Finances y exportadas a un fichero .csv. Su estructura es:
[image: prueba2]
con el siguiente script:

```
 import os
# Recuperar el directorio de trabajo actual (`cwd`)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
# Change directory 
os.chdir("F:\Py_2019\Py_Udacity\Ficheros_Yahoo")
# List all files and directories in current directory
os.listdir('.')
df1 = pd.read_csv("iberdrola.csv", index_col = "Date", parse_dates = True, 
                 usecols = ["Date", "Close"], na_values = ["nan"])
df1["Close"] = df1["Close"].astype(np.float)
print (df1[:3])
print (df1.info())
# Plot the cumulative daily returns
df1["Close"].plot(figsize=(12,8))
_ = plt.legend(loc=2);

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

El resultado es correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PRUEBA Nº 2
Convertimos el fichero Acatis.csv en Acatis.xlsx.
Ejecutamos

```
import os
# Recuperar el directorio de trabajo actual (`cwd`)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
# Change directory 
os.chdir("F:\Py_2019\Py_Udacity\Ficheros_Yahoo")
# List all files and directories in current directory
os.listdir('.')

df2 = pd.read_excel("Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", header=0 )
print (df2[:3])
print (df2.info())
# Plot the cumulative daily returns
df2["Close"].plot(figsize=(12,8))
_ = plt.legend(loc=2);

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

y obtenemos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta prueba parece indicarnos que el fichero Acatis es correcto.

¿Cual puede ser la causa de este problema?.

Comment: que resulatdo te da  `df_R4_selec["Acatis"].describe()`? Tambien `df_R4_selec.loc[0:440,"Acatis"].describe()`?

Comment: El rpimero me da.         count    881.000000
mean     231.578445
std       15.205255
min      201.250000
25%      218.340000
50%      225.520000
75%      245.160000
max      260.110000
Name: Acatis, dtype: float64

Comment: df_R4_selec["Acatis"].describe()   me devuelve:                                           TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Comment: Pues yo no creo que el problema esté en el separador. Lo has especificado correctamente con `decimal=','` al importar, y cuando muestras el dataframe se ve que ha convertido correctamente los decimales. Creo que el problema es que los datos que vienen en el csv realmente están mal y presentan esos patrones raros. ¿Has mirado qué hay en el csv, por ejemplo en los primeros 100 datos y qué muestra el dataframe en esos mismos datos? ¿O a abrir el csv en excel y tratar de crear la gráfica en él?

Comment: Adjunto link al  NoteBook Graficar_csv_R4    https://github.com/akitxu/Aprendiendo-GitHub  el cual incluye todo el código anteriormente mencionado y los ficheros csv y xlsx

Comment: ¿Se te ocurre cual puede ser un título más acertado , para reseñar el problema e  intentar suscitar más curiosidad en otros especialistas?.

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta en "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353280/problema-con-plot-y-el-tipo-de-datos-a-graficar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema deriva de como abría el fichero csv descargado de un banco.

Marcando como Opciones de Separador solamente '\t', el fichero se carga correctamente y la gráfica con Python se ve sin errores.