# plot y tipo de datos a graficar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

En Github, [https://github.com/akitxu/Consultas-Programacion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gslDh.png) se encuentra disponible el notebook y los ficheros que documentan esta consulta. Mi problema es el siguiente.
El script que muestro a continuación, grafica correctamente.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Leer fichero descargado de Renta 4
os.chdir("/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Paso_Peregrino/Ficheros_R4_csv/")
df_temp = pd.read_csv("DedaloPP.csv" ,index_col = "Date",  decimal  =",", parse_dates = ["Date"], 
                      usecols = ["Date", "Close"],  na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t')
df_temp = df_temp.dropna()
df1 = df_temp.reset_index()

#Grafica de las cotizaciones
title =" Cotizaciones de R4 csv"
ax = df_temp.plot(title=title, fontsize=12, figsize=(12,8))
ax.set_xlabel("Fecha")
ax.set_ylabel("Precio")

print (df1.dtypes)
print (df_temp[:3])
print (df_temp.info())
```

Comprobamos que grafica bien y que el tipo de  las fechas del índice de las filas es "object". Esto puede ser debido a lo que se menciona en pandas.read_csv,  [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gslDh.png)    consultando "parse_dates": "...Si una columna o índice no puede representarse como una matriz de fechas y horas, por ejemplo, debido a un valor no analizable o una mezcla de zonas horarias, la columna o índice se devolverá sin alterar como un tipo de datos de objeto 
Como necesito que las fechas sean del tipo "datetime64", antes de graficar convierto el formato "object" al formato "datetime64", y ejecuto el script modificado.

```
# Leer fichero descargado de Renta 4
os.chdir("/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2020/Py_Paso_Peregrino/Ficheros_R4_csv/")
df_temp = pd.read_csv("DedaloPP.csv" ,index_col = "Date",  decimal  =",", parse_dates = ["Date"], 
                      usecols = ["Date", "Close"],  na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t')
df_temp = df_temp.dropna()
df1 = df_temp.reset_index()

df_temp.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_temp["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp["Date"])
pd.to_datetime(df_temp["Date"], errors = "coerce", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
assets = df_temp.set_index("Date")["2016-1-4":"2020-5-5"]

# Normalizar los precios utilizando la primera fila del df 
#assets_filtrado = assets.loc[inicio: fin]
assets_normalizados = assets / assets.iloc[0, :]

# Representación gráfica
title =" Cotizaciones de R4 csv"
ax = assets_normalizados.plot(title=title, fontsize=12, figsize=(12,8))
ax.set_xlabel("Fecha")
ax.set_ylabel("Precio")

assets[:3]
```

La gráfica se muestra distorsionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Al principio he estado centrado en el contenido de los archivos csv descargados. Finalmente, con esta prueba, creo haber centrado el problema en el tipo de datos. ¿Cómo podría conseguir que las fechas importadas lo estén en el formato fecha?. ¿Por qué grafica mal con el formato fecha?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda y aclaraciones.bien.

He probado con el IDE "spyder", convirtiendo los ficheros a xlsx. y el gráfico también sale distorsionado. Fichero de prueba: `pruebas_spyder.py`

Comment: Los ficheros causa del problema, los obtengo de la manera siguiente. Los descargo de la Web de Renta4 en formato .csv. Con "libreoffice"" los abro, preparo su contenido (elimino líneas y columnas, renombro columnas y doy nombre a l ahoja)  y a continuación los guardo como ficheros xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Los ficheros causa del problema, los obtengo de la manera siguiente. Los descargo de la Web de Renta4 en formato .csv. Con "libreoffice"" los abro, preparo su contenido (elimino líneas y columnas, renombro columnas y doy nombre a l ahoja)  y a continuación los guardo como ficheros xlsx.  Hoy he realizado la siguiente prueba alternativa, consistente en importar los ficheros csv en un Libro Excel,

Comment: con la opción "<datos< importar texto" y los guardo como fichero "Excel 97-2003". Realizo su importación con un script python y muestra correctamente la gráfica. No he sido capaz de encontrar la diferencia en el contenido interno de los ficheros que dan el error y los que no, pero creo que ésta prueba es concluyente. Si os parece bien, podríamos proceder a borrar esta consulta dado que posiblemente no aporte nada útil a otros usuarios.